# string to base64 conversion

Tags: python, base64

I'm a python newbie and trying to to some very simple task and encode a text to base64.
I understand that I have to pad my string but the problem is the that padding is also been encoded..:/
this is my code:

```
import base64

b64Val = b64encode(b'this is a test')
print(b64Val)
```

and the result is:

```
b'dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q='
```

My question is ofcource how to remove the b' and the quots from the generated code?
i tried to use this thread [Base64 encoding in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908287/base64-encoding-in-python-3) but apperantly its not working the same as I do get the entire string including the padding chars...
going crazy here..
thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will go away as soon as you write it to a byte-oriented store. Since, of course, they aren't actually *there* in the first place.

```
with open('foo.txt', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(b64Val)
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio! Although im not going to use this in a text file but in a header - you did gave me an idea of how to achieve it.. i can do it by encoding the string to UTF-8 and after the base64 encoding, decode the base64 using the same UTF-8. working just fine! :)