# How to read the JSON request / response which values are encoded in Base64

Tags: json, https, base64, jmeter

I recorded a Mobile Native application (HTTPS/JSON) using Jmeter.

The requests and responses captured as in JSON format and I am not able to view the values that are passed in the requests because they are encoded in base64.

How do I proceed?

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952165/how-to-decode-base-64-format-in-jmeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode Base64 on the fly via [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor).

1. Add Beanshell Post Processor as a child of the request you want to decode
2. Put the following code into Beanshell Post Processor's "Script" area

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
   prev.setResponseData(Base64.decodeBase64(data));
   ```
3. View decoded response via [View Results Tree Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

Explanation:

- [Base64.decodeBase64()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64(byte[])) - self explanatory, it's the method of a class from Commons Codec package which provides Base64 encoding and decoding operations
- `prev` is a shorthand for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance holding result of the parent sampler
- `data` is the byte array representing parent sampler response data.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on what can be done via Beanshell scripting.