# JMeter handling of base64 encoding/decoding and deflate compression/uncompression

Tags: jmeter, base64, deflate

I've captured some HTTP traffic using fiddler but both the request and response have a combination of plain and garbled text.

Example request in raw format:

[image]

The developer advised the request is being base64 encoded first and then compressed using deflate. Likewise the response needs to be base64 decoded and then uncompressed.

How can I handle this in JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Jmeter Plugin [Custom JMeter Functions plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/), It provides base64Encode and base64Decode functions which can be used for your use case.

```
${__base64Encode(test string)}
${__base64Decode(dGVzdCBzdHJpbmc=)}
```

Comment: This plugin truncates my message at a certain point though works to actually encode the string in base64. Please, is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your header contains the below values or include that:-

```
Header Value: gzip,deflate
```

Normally, it should be captured if used jmeter proxy recording.

Ref:-https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/10/24/enable-gzip-compression-jmeter/

For decoding in JSR223 sampler;-

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

vars.put("decoded_response", new String(Base64.decodeBase64(data)));
```

You need to pass the data field or try the solution with custom plugin.

Ref:-[How to decode base 64 format in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952165/how-to-decode-base-64-format-in-jmeter)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode/uncompress the response using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and Groovy language like:

```
prev.setResponseData(new java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(prev.getResponseDataAsString().decodeBase64())).getBytes())
```

`prev` stands for [HTTPSampleResult](http://home.apache.org/~milamber/jmeter-3.0RC5/docs/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html) class instance providing access to all its functions and properties in current context.

Similarly you can use `sampler` shorthand which is for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) in [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to compress/encode the request.

Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more information on using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) components in Groovy scripts

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please note the request, as captured via fiddler, is already encoded and compressed. I need to firstly decode then decompress, modify contents, encode and then compress.