# when convert to base 64, TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, base64

```
im = Image.open(filePath)                     # load image
self.msg = str(bytearray(list(im.getdata()))) # convert image data to string
encodedMsg = base64.b64encode(self.msg)
```

when I was trying to encode the data read from an image to base64, it returns an error:

```
File "Steganography.py", line 42, in msgToXml
    encodedMsg = base64.b64encode(self.msg)
  File "/opt/python3/current/lib/python3.4/base64.py", line 62, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1]
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

It works when I'm home using Ubuntu(python 2.7). But it shows error when I use school machine(python3.4). How can I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
encodedMsg = base64.b64encode(self.msg.encode('ascii'))
```

reference: [Base64 encoding in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908287/base64-encoding-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

In short, it is because in Python3 there was a major overhaul of unicode/string/bytes system. You should read this https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit and this https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html to understand what's happened and how to deal with it.

To answer your specific issue - if you don't convert your bytearray to str, everything should work.

Comment: I read some data from xml file. This code `self.msg = base64.b64decode(self.xml.encode('utf-8'))` returns `File "/opt/python3/current/lib/python3.4/base64.py", line 90, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`