# How to handle post request in google cloud endpoints?

Tags: python, html, forms, google-cloud-endpoints

```
  @endpoints.method(InputClass,OutputClass,
                          path='apipath', http_method='POST',
                          name='something.apiname')
```

and my input class is

```
class InputClass(messages.Message):
    var1 = messages.StringField(1)
    var2 = messages.StringField(2)
#Code to store image data
```

From the above code a service is created that is called from the form with form data. Now on the form there is file field in which user uploads a photo. Now all other form data will get stored in the input class but i don't know how to store image in input class. I mean what would be the message field to store the image data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the photo to [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and send it as a `String` value. You can find lots of examples how to do this e.g. [Base64 encoding in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908287/base64-encoding-in-python-3)

If the photo is large you have to use Blobstore. More about uploading files to blobstore [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/). Once the photo is uploaded to the Blobstore you keep track of its `blobKey`. You can fetch or delete the photo from the Blobstore using the blob key.

Comment: thanks!! But where i would encode the uploaded image that is What should i have to add in input class .. I mean What message field i will use.?

Comment: @SunilKumar I'm not a python guy, so I won't tell you the exact type, but the image will be converted to string representation. You can store it just as you're storing strings.