# Tensorflow serving: Unable to base64 decode

Tags: tensorflow, base64, serving

I use the slim package `resnet_v2_152` to train a classification model.
Then it is exported to .pb file to provide a service.
Because the input is image, so it would be encoded with web-safe base64 encoding. It looks like:

`serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, name='tf_example')`
`decoded = tf.decode_base64(serialized_tf_example)`

I then encode an image with base64 such that:

`img_path = '/Users/wuyanxue/Desktop/not_emoji1.jpeg'`

`img_b64 = base64.b64encode(open(img_path, 'rb').read())`

`s = str(img_b64, encoding='utf-8')`

`s = s.replace('+', '-').replace(r'/', '_')`

My post data is as structured as follow:
`post_data = {
'signature_name': 'predict',
  'instances':[ { 
      'inputs': 
          { 'b64': s }
      }]
}`
Finally, I post a HTTP request to this server:

`res = requests.post('server_address', json=post_data)`

It gives me:

`'{ "error": "Failed to process element: 0 key: inputs of \\\'instances\\\' list. Error: Invalid argument: Unable to base64 decode" }'`

I want to know how it could be encountered? And are there some solutions for that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using python3. I solved it by adding a 'b' - a byte-like object instead of the default str to the encode function:
`b'{"instances" : [{"b64": "%s"}]}' % base64.b64encode(
      dl_request.content)`

Hope that helps, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908287/why-do-i-need-b-to-encode-a-python-string-with-base64) for extra info.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already solved.

```
post_data = {
'signature_name': 'predict',
'instances':[ { 
  'inputs': 
      { 'b64': s }
  }]
}
```

We see that inputs is with 'b64' flag, which illustrates that tensorflow serving will **decode** s with base64 code. 
It belongs to the tensorflow serving internal method.
So, the placeholder:

```
serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, name='tf_example')
```

will directly receive the binary format of the input data BUT NOT base64 format.

So, finally,

```
decoded = tf.decode_base64(serialized_tf_example)
```

is NOT necessary.