# Python 3.7 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, base64

I have these two strings:

```
client_id = "id_str"
client_secret = "secret_str"
```

And I must pass them like so:

```
def getToken(code, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri):
    body = {
        "grant_type": 'authorization_code',
        "code" : code,
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret
    }

    encoded = base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format(client_id, client_secret))
    headers = {"Content-Type" : HEADER, "Authorization" : "Basic {}".format(encoded)} 

    post = requests.post(SPOTIFY_URL_TOKEN, params=body, headers=headers)
    return handleToken(json.loads(post.text))
```

but when I do so I get the error:

```
    encoded = base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format(client_id, client_secret))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How do I fix this encoding/formatting for `Python 3.7`?

ps: I don't see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8908287/3451339) adressing formatting {} as well as encoding.

Comment: Try `binascii.b2a_base64(s.encode(), newline=False)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need 'b' to encode a string with Base64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908287/why-do-i-need-b-to-encode-a-string-with-base64)

Comment: the linked answer does not address formatting.

Comment: @ Александр some error is thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
encoded = base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format(client_id, client_secret))
```

to

```
encoded = base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format(client_id, client_secret).encode())
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html):

> base64.b64encode(s, altchars=None)
>
> Encode the bytes-like object s using Base64 and return the encoded bytes.

Regarding your objection:

> the linked answer does not address formatting

Actually your problem has nothing to do with formatting, because `format()` just returns a string, but `b64encode` requires a bytes-like object, not a string.