# Error while encoding credentials using base64

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to fetch data from Inhouse API where credentials need to encoded using base64.

```
import base64
import requests

username = 'root'
password = '1234'
auth_str = '%s:%s' % (username, password)
b64_auth_str = base64.b64encode(auth_str)

headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % b64_auth_str}

#content_res = requests.get(get_url, headers=headers).json()
```

Above is my code. This throws up error on line where encoding username and password.

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Any work around?

Answer (score 0):

`b64encode` only accepts a bytes-like object, so you need to encode your string into bytes:

```
b64_auth_str = base64.b64encode(auth_str.encode('utf-8'))
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908287/why-do-i-need-b-to-encode-a-string-with-base64).

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the string into bytes:

`b64_auth_str = base64.b64encode(auth_str.encode('utf-8'))`

Answer (score 0):

As You mentioned your error says that the argument which you are passing `b64_auth_str = base64.b64encode(auth_str)` in this case **auth_str should be a Byte like object not a str (string)**

so to solve that problem just **use .encode() function** which is inbuilt in Python3 and when no argument is passed it's converts the string to byte object so you should do this:

`b64_auth_str = base64.b64encode(auth_str.encode('utf-8'))`

Or You Can Do This:

`b64_auth_str = base64.b64encode(auth_str.encode())` Both Work Fine
And when printing the `b64_auth_str` The Output is `b'cm9vdDoxMjM0'`

I Hope This Worked, Jai Hind Jai Bharat